# Chrome localstorage doesn't work property in Mac OS

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I have an extension which require some data from localstorage.
Algorithm:
If data not found (or empty) then alert(); and return;

```
var storage = chrome.storage.local;
storage.get('data', function(items) 
{ 
    if (!items.data.apiKey) { alert('Api key not set!'); return;} // not working
    //nextstuff that is not working if there is no items.data.apiKey
}
```

This code is working great on Windows. In Mac OS it doesn't alert me, neighter return if it doesn't return data.

Comment: Is this "storage" an abstraction of `localStorage`, or actually the [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html) API (not `localStorage`)?

Comment: just completed my code, please check again.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your code does not fail because of OS X.

The real issue is that you're reading a property of `items.data`. By doing this, you assume that `items.data` is a non-empty value (not `null` or `undefined`). This assumption is false.

To solve this, add an extra check:

```
chrome.storage.local.get('data', function(items) { 
    if (!items.data || !items.data.apiKey) {
        alert('Api key not set!');
        return;
    }
});
```

If you wish, you can also set a default value, as follows:

```
chrome.storage.local.get({data: 'default value'}, function(items) { 
    /* ... */
});
```

Comment: That didn`t solved my problem. I just received a Mac and tested. When google chrome extension create the alert i see for about 0.3 sec the message. And then the extension is closing. I think that return may be the problem ?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Create a minimal example that demonstrates the error. If you believe it to be a bug, not a coding mistake, report it at http://crbug.com/new.